# Exception in plugin Android Support

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest, android-support-library

Suddenly when I was running my android application project, Android Studio shows an error balloon of **Internal Error**

Then my manifest suddenly got errors saying

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Activity name cannot be empty.
```

[image: Errors in Manifest]
[image: Bug?]

I tried disabling the Android Plugin and restarting it back again but no use.
I also have error on **R not being resolved** but I think it is because it can't read my manifest file.

I also tried `Build -> Clean Project` but still no luck.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try File | Invalidate Caches and restart

Comment: I also did try that. It was a mistake that I haven't included it in the question.

Comment: Related to your problem I want to tell my event. Once I wanted to change the field name in one of my model class as given "String name" right clicked and refactor, rename then I gave fName  then I clicked some bunch of OK button... I didnt realized at the beggining but I my accepting caused many change in "string", "style", "color" and in "dimens" every name filed  has been changed to "fName". That is why in manifest file cant read the informations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that it is a refactor bug.

I refactored a variable named `name` to `description` then Android Studio replaces the ones in the xml files too, in my case the <`item name="">` -> `<item description="">`

Comment: had the same issue. what the heck :)

Answer (score 0):

It basically happens due to **buildToolsVersion** . For me i was using buildToolVersion "23.0.0", changing it freshly installed "23.0.2" solved my error .So

> Change **BuildToolsVersion** to latest one like in my case 23.0.0 to **23.0.2**

and then build gradle again.

Comment: In my case, after an Android Studio update, I started getting this error. So then I updated build.gradle - I went from 26.0.1 back to 26.0.0 and it started working ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯